# Custom android checkbox single selection in listview

Tags: android-listview, android-checkbox

I want to set single selection checkbox in listview.
In this listview contain 2 textview, one button and one checkbox by each row.
textview data retrieve from sqlite database so, when I check on checkbox, another checkbox is unchecked and check only click checkbox in list view.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checkable layout for that.

1. Make a checkable class like this [Checkable linear layout
   tutorial](http://tokudu.com/post/50023900640/android-checkable-linear-layout)
2. Insert the checkable layout in you xml class, like this:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <com.example.xxx.widget.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:padding="10dp" >
   //Your checkbox and textview here
   </com.example.xxx.widget.CheckableLinearLayout>`
3. In your onItemClick insert this code

   ```
      if (itemcheck.isChecked()) {
                   itemcheck.setChecked(true);
               } else {
                   itemcheck.setChecked(false);
               } 
                   itemcheck.setChecked(true);
   ```

Comment: Please down give link-only answers. The given link may be dead in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (position != selected && mSelectedRB != null)
                {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }
                selected = position;
                mSelectedRB = (CheckBox) view;
                //database.deleteAllRecords();
                //database.insertRecord(rowItems.get(position).getLanguageID(), rowItems.get(position).getLanguage(), rowItems.get(position).getImageUrl());
            }
        });

        if(selected != position)
        {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            if(holder.checkbox != null && holder.checkbox != mSelectedRB)
            {
                mSelectedRB = holder.checkbox;
            }

        }
        //context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LanguageActivity.class));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    LanguageDetails rowItem = (LanguageDetails) getItem(position);

    holder.checkbox.setText(rowItem.getLanguage());
    return convertView;
}`
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution?